# Cannot resolve symbol "symbol_name" + private field "column_name" is never used

Tags: android, sqlite

I am copying a youtube video tutorial about Login-Signup in SQLite database in android studio (by Tech Academy) and I encountered this error:

[database helper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EHHde.png)

Can someone help? Many thanks in advance.

DatabaseHelper class:

```
package com.example.haryo.loginshits;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

/**
 * Created by Haryo on 09/01/2018.
 */

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = contacts.db;
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = contacts;
    private static final String COLUMN_ID = id;
    private static final String COLUMN_NAME = name;
    private static final String COLUMN_EMAIL = email;
    private static final String COLUMN_UNAME = uname;
    private static final String COLUMN_PASS = pass;
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    private static final String TABLE_CREATE = "create table contacts (id integer primary key not null auto_increment ," +
            " name text not null , email text not null , uname text not null , pass text not null);";

    public DatabaseHelper (Context context){
        super (context , DATABASE_NAME , null , DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(TABLE_CREATE);
        this.db = db;
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        String query = "DROP TABLE IF EXIST " +TABLE_NAME;
        db.execSQL(query);
        this.onCreate(db);
    }
}
```

Comment: you just pass all your column and database name in double quotes..loke this.  =  String TABLE_NAME = "contacts"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this to-:

```
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = contacts.db;
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = contacts;
    private static final String COLUMN_ID = id;
    private static final String COLUMN_NAME = name;
    private static final String COLUMN_EMAIL = email;
    private static final String COLUMN_UNAME = uname;
    private static final String COLUMN_PASS = pass;
```

To-:

```
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "contacts.db";
        private static final String TABLE_NAME = "contacts";
        private static final String COLUMN_ID = "id";
        private static final String COLUMN_NAME = "name";
        private static final String COLUMN_EMAIL = "email";
        private static final String COLUMN_UNAME = "uname";
        private static final String COLUMN_PASS = "pass";
```

In Android String values are represented by "".

Comment: damn you are right.
I'm such an idiot.. just learning code for few weeks.
Many thank tough

Answer (score 1):

Column fields should be strings, which are wrapped using double quotes as in

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "contacts.db";
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "contacts";
    private static final String COLUMN_ID = "id";
    private static final String COLUMN_NAME = "name";
    private static final String COLUMN_EMAIL = "email";
    private static final String COLUMN_UNAME = "uname";
    private static final String COLUMN_PASS = "pass";
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    private static final String TABLE_CREATE = "create table "+TABLE_NAME+" ("+COLUMN_ID+" integer primary key not null auto_increment ," +COLUMN_NAME+
            " text not null , "+COLUMN_EMAIL+" text not null , "+COLUMN_UNAME+" text not null , "+COLUMN_PASS+" text not null);";

    public DatabaseHelper (Context context){
        super (context , DATABASE_NAME , null , DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(TABLE_CREATE);
        this.db = db;
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        String query = "DROP TABLE IF EXIST " +TABLE_NAME;
        db.execSQL(query);
        this.onCreate(db);
    }
}
```